# How to get count of rollup summary, formula field, relationship field(Both lookup and master-detail) on an sObject in apex salesforce?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to build a Lightning Web Component in which user will select a sObject and the object limit related to that sObject will show, like **how many rollup summary, formula field, relationship field(both lookup and master-detail separately) has been made** and how many of each of them we can make on sObject. Somewhat similar to object limit tab shown on a sObject.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Tooling api provided by salesforce..
here is the link for refence.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by JJangid, I suggest you look into Tooling API. There is the object [EntityLimit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitylimit.htm) that holds some of these limits for objects:

```
SELECT Label, Max, Remaining, Type
FROM EntityLimit
WHERE
  EntityDefinition.DeveloperName = 'Account'
```

This will result in something like the following:

| Label | Max | Remaining | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Custom Fields | 800 | 591 | CustomFields |
| Rollup Summary Fields | 30 | 19 | RollupSummary |
| Custom Relationship Fields | 40 | 9 | CustomRelationship |
| Active Workflow Rules | 300 | 281 | ActiveRules |
| Total Workflow Rules | 500 | 479 | TotalRules |
| Approval Processes | 500 | 500 | ApprovalProcesses |
| Active Lookup Filters | 5 | 3 | ActiveLookupFilters |
| Active Validation Rules | 500 | 492 | ActiveValidationRules |
| VLOOKUP Functions | 10 | 10 | VLookup |
| Sharing Rules (Both Owner- and Criteria-based) | 300 | 259 | SharingRules |

Comment: Thanks for your response!!
But it lack some information I need like rollup summary, formula field

Comment: Sure, thanks. I see the `RollupSummary`. Does it help? For formulas, it is worth checking your environment.